# Elasticsearch search query issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I am not being able to get the hits from the elasticsearch server. My code-

```
client = Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true
client.indices.refresh index: 'property_index'
# search_results = client.search(body: { query: { multi_match: { query: search_params, fields: ['street_address', 'suburb'] } } })
match_query = [
  { match: { status: 'Active'} }
]
match_query << { match: { is_published: true} }
match_query << { match: { paid: true} }
match_query << { match: { suburb: params[:suburb].to_s} } if !params[:suburb].blank?
match_query << { match: { advertise_type: params[:advertise_type].to_s} } if !params[:advertise_type].blank?
match_query << { match: { state: params[:state].to_s} } if !params[:state].blank?
match_query << { match: { postal_code: params[:postal_code]} } if !params[:postal_code].blank?
response = client.search(body: {
                                  query: { bool: { must: match_query }},
                                  sort: [
                                    { updated_at: { order: "desc" }}
                                  ]
                              }, from: params[:offset], size: params[:limit])

all_records = client.search(body: {
                query: { bool: { must: match_query }},
                sort: [
                  { updated_at: { order: "desc" }}
                ]
              })
```

This is the response output that i am getting-

```
GET http://localhost:9200/_search?from=0&size=10 [status:200, request:0.010s, query:0.003s]
```

2018-11-20 18:25:34 +0530: > {"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"status":"Active"}},{"match":{"is_published":true}},{"match":{"paid":true}},{"match":{"advertise_type":"Sell"}}]}},"sort":[{"updated_at":{"order":"desc"}}]}
2018-11-20 18:25:34 +0530: < {"took":3,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
2018-11-20 18:25:34 +0530: GET http://localhost:9200/_search [status:200, request:0.008s, query:0.002s]
2018-11-20 18:25:34 +0530: > {"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"status":"Active"}},{"match":{"is_published":true}},{"match":{"paid":true}},{"match":{"advertise_type":"Sell"}}]}},"sort":[{"updated_at":{"order":"desc"}}]}
2018-11-20 18:25:34 +0530: < {"took":2,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}

Comment: please provide more information... error and logs

Comment: i am not getting any errors but i will post the information log

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of difficult to tell what's wrong if we do not know about the structure or what you're trying to achieve with the query.

The information log says the following:

```
timed_out:false
Shards:
 total:1 
 successful: 1
 failed:0
Hits: 
 total: 0
```

Which means, that the query was successful, and the server encountered no errors. It just did not find any matching documents to your query.

I'd recommend using a proper tool to first try your queries, for an example Kibanas' search profiler (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/xpack-profiler.html).

This shows you information about your query, once you find your query suitable, you can integrate it into your code.

Comment: i am trying to get all the records which match the match_query from the table. But the problem is i am always getting nil in HITS

Comment: Lets say i want to achieve something like this - `http://localhost:9200/property_index/_search?size=1000&pretty=true&q=*:*`